# Html multidimensional array in

Tags: html, arrays

I would like to pass multiple value with check box,is any provision to pass multiple value using 
check box in html.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="1">
```

please suggest me how should be it is possible

Comment: How about CSV ? `value="1,2,3"` OR use multiple checkboxes with same name but different values

Comment: Thanks sir, but i have to use 6 check box so how should i pass multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[0][]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[0][]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[1][]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[1][]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[1][]" value="5">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['service_id']))
    var_export($_POST['service_id']);
```

Comment: i need like this<input type="checkbox" name="service_id[][]" value="5">

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one value per input. If you want to have multiple values, then either:

- give each set of values a unique identifier and resolve it on the server
- encode the data in a format like JSON or CSV and then parse it on the server

If you want to have multiple inputs with different values, then just create multiple elements in the HTML.

PHP will discard all but one of them if they come from inputs which share a name and that name doesn't end with `[]`, but your name does:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="1">
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="2">
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="3">
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="4">
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="5">
 <input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" value="6">
```